# When creating canvases in JS and drawing text, text is overwitten when creating more

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, es6-class

I am trying to create a program where a user fills in the fields and a "post" (a canvas with text written on it) is displayed.

So far, I have successfully managed to create the canvas but filling it in with text is the problem.

There is a separate function in the ES6 Class to add the text to the canvas.

I also have a function which creates a new "Post" and displays text on it.

I am using that function to test the program however the text is overwritten on top of the other text on the first canvas created.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

class Post {
    constructor(height, width, user) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.user = user;
        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    addText(text, color) {
        let canvas = document.getElementById(this.id);
        let contextCanvas = canvas.getContext('2d');
        contextCanvas.fillStyle = color;
        contextCanvas.fillText(text + " by " + this.user, 5, 30);
    }
    addBreak() {
        let br = document.createElement("br");
        body.appendChild(br);
    }
};

var createBox = async (textP, userP) => {
    let text = textP;
    let user = userP;
    let textColor = "black";

    let boxCreate = new Post(200, 200, user);
    boxCreate.addText(text, textColor);
    boxCreate.addBreak();
}

//drawPosts();

createBox("hi", "i am one.");
createBox("hello", "i am two.");
createBox("hey", "i am three.");
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS to highlight the canvases:

```
canvas  {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Define `canvas` and `contextCanvas` as the properties of the class. Now you're recreating the context every time you're printing text to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Teemu said, just define canvas and contextCanvas as properties of the class.